# PHP PDO prepare statement with parameterized column in SELECT clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am learning PHP Pdo and I got a question and answer.

Assuming that the PDO connection is valid. the following code returns none because the prepared statement is invalid.

I want to know why/how the prepared statement is invalid.

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$sql = "SELECT :cols FROM names WHERE name = :name";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':cols', 'COUNT(id)');
$stmt->bindValue(':name', 'anna');
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You can't bind columns `SELECT :cols`

Comment: Why do you want to bind `COUNT(id)` instead of just writing it there as-is?

Comment: Use `"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM names WHERE name = :name"` as the query instead; also, I'm not sure how this is related to `__get` and `__set`.